# How do I use With XMLNamespaces to create custom name spaces in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces, for-xml

I want to be able to produce the following namesspaces and types for an XML root element

`<BaseTransactionRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" i:type="AType">`

Typically the first 2 (that is, not including i:type="AType")  can be produced without issue (with some tradeoffs, when using custom namespaces we  cant represent nulls using the xmlns:ni namespace etc) 
So, the latter type is problematic.  For a referesher, 
the WITH XMLNAMESPACES fearure is used like below (FOR XML part omitted):

`;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i,                     DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany',`

A solution to overcome was to write XML "literally" using string concatenation.  But I believe and hope FOR XML and this can be used together.

EDIT: First cut was added in a real rush.  Apologies.
EDIT2: Dyslexic fix

Comment: `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i,
 DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany')
select 'AType' as [i:Type]
from (select 1 as ID) t
for xml raw('BaseTransactionRequest')` seems to produce exactly the XML you're asking for. So what's the issue? It would help if you're unable to make this work if you could create a *complete* sample rather than just giving us a fragment to work from.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wen hat the same idea, the same minute... I think that the OP mis-takes the `i:type="AType"` as a kind of namespace...

Comment: @Damian Thankyou.  You have provided me with a solution. I had an issue, you didn't. If I don't know about something I will certainly ask questions. Well done.

Comment: The OP certainly does mistake namespace for something else. You learned lot could tell me without guffawing about an inability to distinguish something. Terrible snobbery on both your parts.

Comment: @brumScouse What's wrong here? Why are you impolite? You are asking random strangers to spend their private time helping you. Nobody was impolite to you! What you call *terrible snobbery* is nothing else then stating a fact trying to help you out of your misconception. C'mon, nobody was staring at you! Happy Coding!

Comment: You are correct, you helped me. but I would also be correct in saying that the answers are also patronising/condescending.  Perhaps I take myself too seriously.

Comment: @brumScouse *but I would also be correct in saying that the answers are also patronising/condescending* - No. What do you expect? You ask for help and someone who knows better tells you  what's wrong. Telling you about a misconception is neither impolite, nor patronising or condescending. It's just pointing to the spot, where you were thinking in the wrong direction. The title of you question still proves this fact. Perhaps you should just vote and accept, if this helped you out, and close this question. Happy Coding!

Comment: I see you were the subject of trolling yesterday and I apologise for this.   

This was not me and I didn't create another account myself to do this.  However,  the part of the answer " but my magic crystal ball is right back from cleaning and showed me," is patronising. I will have to agree to disagree. Thankyou for your time.

Comment: @brumScouse, good to clearify this, thank you! I can tell you for sure, that this is not meant patronising. Just [look at this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5089204+magic) that I use this metapher quite often. Often questions are not very clear, so is yours, and it needs some intuitive understanding (emphathy, "magic crystal balls") to get the real issue and provide an appropriate answer. It was meant funny, sorry if you felt offended...

Comment: @brumScouse, I have edited my answer... Just a hint: Without a `@Shnugo` in your comment, there's no alert triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... You might have a misconception about your `i:type="AType"`. This is not a *namespace* (whatever a *custom namespace* is), but a normal attribute, named `type` living in your namespace `i`, which is declared at `xmlns:i="blah"`.

Try this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i
                   ,DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany')
SELECT 'AType' AS [@i:type]
FOR XML PATH('BaseTransactionRequest');
```

The result is a self closing tag, declaring two namespaces and containing your attribute:

```
<BaseTransactionRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeCompany" 
                        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        i:type="AType" />
```

Comment: Hi downvoter, any reason for your downvote? I dislike downvotes without a comment... This is - uhm - cowardish...